# Why shouldn't I use GC.Collect()

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, certificate-authority

I am developing an application where I work with CertAdm.dll to make connections to a Certificate Authority. Sometimes I get the error **"An attempt was made to open a Certification Authority database session, but there are already too many active sessions. The server may need to be configured to allow additional sessions."**

If I configure my connection like the code below, I dont get the error and all works fine.

```
CERTADMINLib.ICertView2 cv2 = new CERTADMINLib.CCertViewClass();

try
{
    cv2.OpenConnection(srtCAConfig);
}
catch
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    cv2.OpenConnection(srtCAConfig);
}
```

Now what I am wondering about is that I have read a lot where people say you shouldn't use GC.Collect(). Why shouldn't I? It solves my problem?

All help is very appreciated.

Comment: [Scott Holdens Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottholden/archive/2004/12/28/339733.aspx) is an answer to that question.

Comment: Because if `GC.Collect` "fixes" your application, it's an indication that you've got serious problems elsewhere. You need to figure out why you're leaking memory and fix that, instead of patching the symptoms.

Comment: also GC.Collect is just a recommendation to the VM to trigger a collection. it can't be guaranteed that it actually is collecting.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Garbage collection becomes less efficient the more you do it.

Waiting for pending finalisers is also undesirable. You are holding up your code to wait for an unknown number of objects to perform cleanup operations that could take an unknown amount of time. If you fixed the underlying problem, there'd be no need to wait for any of them.

As for the underlying problem, when an object owns some external (scarce) resource, it's important that when you're done with it, you call the appropriate method to release the resource. Often that's a method called Dispose(), CloseConnection() or something similar.

however, this is a COM interop object and all MSDN says is

> To close the connection, call the Release function (C++) or set the object to Nothing (Visual Basic).

In .NET, the equivalent is to call System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cv2). Once you've done that, the object referred to by cv2 is invalid, so don't call it again.

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cv2) does not solve my problem, I still get the error. I want close the the connection but Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cv2) doesnt do that. I dont know what do do :S

Comment: @Erik, just to double-check: _Every_ time you create a new CCertViewClass instance, you are (1) calling OpenConnection on it, (2) using it, and then (3) calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject on it. Correct?

Comment: @Erik, if that doesn't work but the finaliser does manage to close it, then that suggests that you have some other COM interop object that references your CCertViewClass internally. I'd guess that the objects returned by EnumCertViewColumn and OpenView might be responsible, so I suggest you call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on those too.

Comment: @acorey: I think your guess is right. I just tried it out, and it seems to work. Thanks and +1!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it solves your problem because of incorrect work with connections in your class.

Try to examine all about connections in your app, see where they are opened and where closed - I think that you don't close connections / don't clear resources that are used by your connections.

Comment: Have you done anything with Certificates yet? Because it seems to me like you don't.

Comment: There is no differece - Certificates or not. GC fixed bugs are serious bugs in your app.

Comment: I know that my problem is closing the connection. And doing this Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cv2) doese not help :S

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not closing the connections after opening them and finally it exceeds the maximum number of connections that can be open at a time. When you give GC.Collect(), each and every time the connection object is forcefully collected , because of which you cannot reuse the already open connection.